# How to draw a scatter chart with multiple columns of metadata+labels?

Tags: pgfplots, formatting, color

I want to print a scatter chart and color the nodes according to a column in the data file. The problem is, `point meta` already is used for other data. This is the class of the point, either ONE or TWO, it is used for the mark. Also, the nodes are labeled.

So how to do this?

Working example:

```
\input{include_filename} % defines \outputfile, written by batchjob
\documentclass[border=5pt,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}%
    \setlength{\textwidth}{500pt}%
    \setlength{\linewidth}{500pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot+[
    scatter, only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
        ONE={mark=*,mark color=\myerror},%             <-- here is the problem
        TWO={mark=triangle*,mark color=\myerror}},%
    nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\myindex}},
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{error} \as \myerror},
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{index} \as \myindex},
]
    table[meta=partition]{\outputfile};     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Scatter chart]

The datafile looks like this:

```
x   y   error   partition   index
-86 -27 0   ONE 3
```

`error` might be quite a large negative number. Like -35547923 e.g.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your marker color should be taken from a color map, right?

I believe a simple solution would be to use `error` as input for `point meta`. That way, you get the mapping into the color map for free. Of course, we will need to use a different key to satisfy `scatter/classes`. My idea is that we simply exchange the value of `point meta` right before `scatter/classes` reads it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]

\addplot+[
    scatter, only marks,
    point meta=\thisrow{error},
    % use this key merely to define 'mapped color' based on the error
    % value. The '{}' overrides the default 'draw' and 'fill' options
    % of 'use mapped color':
    scatter/use mapped color={},
    % now, append code which RESETS \pgfplotspointmeta to \partition.
    % This will become the input to 'scatter/classes*':
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append code={%
        \let\pgfplotspointmeta=\partition
    },%
    scatter/classes*={
        ONE={mark=*,mapped color},%
        TWO={mark=triangle*,mapped color}},%
    nodes near coords*={\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\myindex}},
    %
    % use 'value ' here : partition should not be parsed as number.
    visualization depends on={value \thisrow{partition} \as \partition},
    visualization depends on={\thisrow{index} \as \myindex},
]
    table[meta=partition]{
        x   y   error   partition   index
        -86 -27 0   ONE 3
        -0 -100 -15547923   ONE 42
        50 -200 -35547923   TWO 4
    };     
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `/.append code` does the same as `scatter/classes*` and `nodes near coords*`: it appends code to `pre marker code`. Since these are applied in the specified order, we can reset point meta in-between.

Comment: Thanks to the author of pgfplots, the documentation is really great and full of good examples!

Comment: Thanks for the praise! I am glad `pgfplots` proves to be useful.